# Public Tor dot Onion addresses for Polkadot, Kusama and Edgeware nodes

Tags: polkadot, kusama, nodes

Hello Polkadot Ecosystem!

There are several public node operators, however, I was not able to find one that had support for .onion addresses. Public .onion nodes is something that has been in the bitcoin space for a while, just like host Bitcoin's electrum wallet has tor onion address support/integration, a public .onion node hosting provider is something that we want to see so we can increase privacy-friendly ways for clients and users to connect.

Public .onion nodes for Polkadot, Kusama and Edgeware are now available here:
https://privhost.laissez-faire.trade/

Answer (score 1):

Public .onion nodes for Polkadot, Kusama and Edgeware are available here now:
https://privhost.laissez-faire.trade/